# How to wp_query every Sunday between a startdate and enddate?

Tags: wp-query

I'm trying to output all Sundays between 2 different dates (startdate and enddate). The following PHP code made this work pefectly. But how to get these dates by the WP_Query?

PHP example (works):

```php
$startDate = new DateTime('2021-08-01');
$endDate = new DateTime('2021-08-31');
$sundays = array();
while ($startDate <= $endDate) {
    if ($startDate->format('w') == 0) {
        $sundays[] = $startDate->format('Y-m-d');
    }
    $startDate->modify('+1 day');
}
foreach($sundays as $sundayItem) {
    echo $sundayItem.'<br>';
}
```

The above code outputs the following:

```
2021-08-01
2021-08-08
2021-08-15
2021-08-22
2021-08-29
```

What I am trying in the WP_Query:

```php
$agenda_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'mm_agenda',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'agenda_startdate',
    'orderby' => 'agenda_startdate',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'agenda_startdate',
            'value' => '2021-08-01',
            'compare' => '>'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'agenda_enddate',
            'value' => '2021-08-31',
            'compare' => '<'
        ),
    ),
));
```

Does anyone has the answer, to get this work? How to integrate that Sunday within the wp_query? And let the foreach outputs the same as the regular PHP method. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: A single post has a meta value of `agenda_date`? or does it always has a start sate and a end date, if it has both do they have the same value or also a range?

Comment: Good question. It always has a startdate and enddate. In this case there is always a gap between startddate and enddate. Like the example I provided.

Comment: So a post can have, for example, agenda_startdate of 2021-08-03 and agenda_enddate of 2021-08-11, am I correct?

Comment: Exactly, correct. And in this example I want to output all the Sundays between those 2 dates.

Comment: so a post with agenda_startdate of 2021-08-03 and agenda_enddate of 2021-08-11 will be outputed by a post with agenda_startdate of 2021-08-03 and agenda_enddate of 2021-08-05 will not, is that correct?

Comment: Let me be a bit more clear. I have a custom post type called 'Agenda' (Events), in which you can create a new post. You can give it a title (for example 'Bingo') and add some custom meta values, like startdate, enddate and specific day (that day is the chosen day between those 2 dates). So for example the user selects Sunday. That means the Bingo event will be available on every Sunday between 2021-08-01 and 2021-08-31. You got this?

Comment: Ohhh so you are using the events plugin, its [this](https://theeventscalendar.com/) one if I remember correctly. I'm not sure you will have the option to do that using WP_Query, they have some internal logic to display the post in the relevant date. Try contacting the plugin support to see if they can help you.

Comment: No I created my own custom Post Type, with those meta values.

Comment: You need to clarify what you're querying. Are you looking for events that start on a given set of Sundays? All events that take place on any Sunday between two dates?